# Import data along with color in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to import data from google spreadsheet to another sheet along with the color which is present in original sheet.

Comment: Manual "copy+paste" does it by default. In script you can use [Range.copyTo(destination) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination). What is the problem?

Comment: I want imported sheet should  automatically updated  when some change occur in original sheet along with the color of cell.please provide the code for the same

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to have **full copy** of the source sheet each time after editing. The target sheet should be **in the same spreadsheet**. Is it right?

Comment: Yes i want all updates which has been done in source sheet in the other spreadsheet in which i have applied import range formula of the source sheet.The target sheet should be in other spreadsheet not in the source sheet.

Comment: Some details still remain unclear. (1) Is it enough to copy colors only once? Will they change? (2) Is it enough to update the range/sheet on open target spreadsheet?

Comment: (1) No every time when source sheet get update whether it is related to color, number or whatever it should get update in the imported sheet.(2)Yes it is enough

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution is below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var previousCopy = destination.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (previousCopy) previousCopy.setName('Dirty');
}


function getSheetCopy() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dirty = destination.getSheetByName('Dirty');
  Logger.log(dirty);
  if (!dirty) return;
  destination.deleteSheet(dirty);
  // Replace sourceId by required identifier,
  // and replace sheetName value as required
  var sourceId = '1el850cyzxy4PrL2uDhN7Dr9vWNX3cGA5-ks1amAX-Ak',
      sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceId);
  source.getSheetByName(sheetName).copyTo(destination).setName(sheetName);
}
```

The idea is to make a full copy (mirror) of the source sheet every time we open a target (destination) spreadsheet. **onOpen** trigger only marks the previous copy as "Dirty". It has limited [AuthMode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/auth-mode) and can not do updates itself.

First time you should make empty "Sheet1" to get ready for automated updates...

Time triggered **getSheetCopy** does the main work and removes "Dirty" mark once. Trigger period is 1 minute (minimal). So when open a spreadsheet, you can see if the mirrored sheet is "Dirty" (not updated) or already actual.

Comment: I have updated the code in app script as mentioned by you but no data along with its color is not coming in destination sheet only Dirty get updated in sheet tab nothing else.Also i am not applying import range function in destination sheet.Let me know if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: The script above was tested. It must have sufficient rights to operate with external source spreadsheet. Check **sourceId** and **sheetName** values... Check logs. Add more logging for locate the problem, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the solution now it is working but what is happening every time whenever i update something in source sheet and run function again then it throws error that particular sheet name already exist.To overcome this first i have to delete that tab and then again run the function to get the updated data in same tab.So i want one more help is there a way that after every 5 min that tab which was created earlier should automatically delete and that "function getSheetCopy" should automatically run to get the updated data.

Comment: Pay attention to **sheetName** in both functions. Coping appears only if "Dirty" sheet is found and deleted. "Dirty" appears only if "Sheet1" is found. I have had no errors during testing with these names. Share your code as readonly, if you need help.

Comment: Also share the error screenshot and log results to locate the error, please.

Comment: Yes that is correct and it is working but is it possible that after every 5 min interval that tab which was created earlier should automatically delete and "function getSheetCopy" should automatically run to get the updated data in sheet with same name which was deleted earlier

Comment: Yes, if you want regular (5 min period) updates, exactly as onOpen, **it is possible**. We should add some persistent "counter variable" and increment it inside time triggered getSheetCopy function from 1 to 5. This is a general idea, here we can implement it in the above code.

Comment: Hi Александр Ермолин the problem has been resolved but what is happening now when sheet is getting deleted and new sheet is created with the same name after running app script i am getting "Unresolved sheet name" error in particular cell  where i am putting formula in different sheet of that sheet name, so is there any way  by which sheet is not get deleted but get auto refreshed after updating something in original sheet so that i will not get error for the same

Comment: I am not sure to understand all the task details. However, if you have other cells dependent on the replacing sheet you should update them (or their formulas) right after each replacement in the same script. In more complex cases it is worth to rearrange data distribution according to their dependency.